# Cannot get the two places of 2 equal numbers in an array

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that will identify what the biggest number is, while I make an array of 20 variables. I am trying to check if I have 2 numbers that are the same as well as they are the biggest. If they are the same, then I want to show both numbers. For some reason, it always writes the biggest number but it always shows that there are 2 arrays which the biggest number was the same as it was the biggest but one of the two numbers in the array is wrong. can you help me make it right?
Thank you!

```
        int b,c=Integer.MIN_VALUE,d = 0,r = 0;
        boolean s= false;
        int[] a = new int[20];
        for(b = 0 ; b < a.length ; b++) {
            a[b] = (int) (Math.random()*899+100);
            System.out.print(a[b] + "     ");
            if(a[b]==c) {
                r = b;
                s = true;
            }
                
            if(a[b]>= c) {
                c = a[b];
                d = b;
            }


        }
        if (s = true) {
            System.out.println("the biggest number was " + c + " and it was placed in the array at " + d + " as well as at " + r + " place" );
            
            
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("the biggest number was " + c + " and it was placed in the array at " + d);
            
        }
```

Comment: Not related to your solution but considering naming your variables better. it clears things up a lot and makes your code more understandable even for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the two `if` inside the `for`.

If you have `a[b] == c`, then both of the `if` will be read. So, this is working:

```java
int b,c=Integer.MIN_VALUE,d = 0,r = 0;
boolean s= false;
int[] a = new int[20];
for(b = 0 ; b < a.length ; b++) {
     a[b] = (int) (Math.random()*899+100);
     System.out.print(a[b] + "     ");

     if(a[b] > c) {
          s = false ;
          c = a[b];
          d = b;
      } else if(a[b] == c) {
          s = true;
          r = b;
      }
}

if (s) {
     System.out.println("the biggest number was " + c + " and it was placed in the array at " + d + " as well as at " + r + " place" );
} else {
     System.out.println("the biggest number was " + c + " and it was placed in the array at " + d);
}
```

I corrected your last `if` to display the result too.